# Field formula with Case/If statement

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I want to set a formula for a field **C** by check two picklist fields **A** and **B** (the value in the picklist will Yes, No, None)

```
 If field A = "Yes" and field B = "Yes"  then field C = "1"
 If field A = "Yes" and field B <> "Yes"  then field C = "2"
 If field A <> "Yes" and field B = "Yes"  then field C = "3"
 If field A <> "Yes" and field B <> "Yes"  then field C = "4"
```

I don't know how to set a formula for field C to make it works, I try CASE, IF statement without any luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to spend some times on these trailhead: [Use Formula Fields](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields) and [Advanced Formulas](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas).
Bookmarking [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5) documentation page would be useful too.

Since `A` and `B` are picklist fields you must use `ISPICKVAL(field, value)`.
If `C` is a text formula field:

```
IF( ISPICKVAL(A, 'Yes'),
    IF ( ISPICKVAL(B, 'Yes'),
        '1',
        '2'
    ),
    IF ( ISPICKVAL(B, 'Yes'),
        '3',
        '4'
    )
)
```